# How to efficiently have multiple child project in IONIC + Angular?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have an IONIC 3 project, that needs to be cloned/forked/multiplied for other clients. I am trying to figure out - the most efficient way for future maintainability of these growing number of projects with common functionality.

Each sequential project will share to a great extend the functionalities of the core (current app). There will eventually come some additional functionalities for every new child app. On the other hand, the core features (auth and almost all API calls, etc.) will stay the same for all but still continuously further developed. 
However, styles and template will be totally different for each project.

I can imagine, that something like this can be maybe achieved with customized npm builds, but with the same single repository. I really do not find grooming and maintaining multiple repos a good idea.

What is your experience? Can you give me a tip on how have some of you achieved this?

Thanks a lot! Looking forward to read your recommendations

Comment: I think you should try this:https://nx.dev/angular

Comment: Thanks @Chellappan! I will definitely take a deeper look into this. Looks very promising for my case.